# Sticky Nav Sticks Too Late

Tags: javascript, sticky

I'm creating a page with sticky nav and it doesn't stick to the top immediately after the header image moves away (it's less than full page size). It only sticks after the size of one full page image has passed. The text inside the nav bar also moves after it sticks.

You can view the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zinctan/7a436ojz/

This is my javascript:

```
$(function() {

// when we scroll down the window, do this:
$(window).scroll(function(){

    //Getting the scroll percentage
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollPercentage =  (scrollHeight / windowHeight);
    console.log(scrollPercentage);

    // if we have scrolled past 200, add the alternate class to nav bar
    if(scrollPercentage > 1) {
        $('.navHighlighter').addClass('scrolling');
    } else {
        $('.navHighlighter').removeClass('scrolling');
    }

});

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
}); // code courtesy of CSS-Tricks

// apply the class of nav-active to the current nav link
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li.nav-active').removeClass('nav-active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('nav-active');
});


// get an array of 'href' of each a tag

var navLink = $('ul.navHighlighter a');
console.log(navLink);
var aArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < navLink.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var aChild = navLink[i];
    var navArray = $(aChild).attr('href');
    console.log(navArray);
    aArray.push(navArray);
    console.log(aArray);
    var selector = aArray.join(" , ");
    console.log(selector);
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var tops = [];

    $(selector).each(function(){
        var top = $(this).position().top - 90;
        if(scrollTop > top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.nav-active').removeClass('nav-active');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').parent().addClass('nav-active');
        }
        tops.push(top);
    });

});
```

});

Any help would be useful! Thank you :)

Comment: Please fix your indentation on your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a good practice to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

and then write your jQuery code in that function in order to assure that your script code will run after your html web page is fully loaded.

Now, I think that that should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topDist = $(".navHighlighter").position(); //save the position of your navbar, better use an id for that
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > topDist.top) { //when the scrolling reaches the very top of your navbar
            $('.navHighlighter').addClass('scrolling');
        } else {
            $('.navHighlighter').removeClass('scrolling');
        }
    });
    *rest of your code goes here*
});
```

Also, add:

```
top:0;
width: 100%;
```

to your .scrolling class in order to command your navbar to start just at the top of the user's window and to cover the whole width of the web page (position:fixed creates some issues on that so you have to set the width of your element, remember that).

I hope I helped and I got your demands right. Happy coding! :)